# Re-Launching the same page using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, automation, tampermonkey

I have a requirement of auditing the users on my company. But unfortunately this is not a straightforward task as it has to be done manually. One-by-one. Hence I was hoping I could use tampermonkey to automate the task.

The problem I am encountering is, I have a list of emails which I want to be searched against my companies database. So when I launch the page the first time the script manages to search the first user from the list but then the page just stops there. It doesn't reload and picks up from where it stopped the last time automatically. If I were to re-load the page it displays the result of the second email from the list. I was hoping to entirely automate this so that I wouldn't have to manually hit the reload button each time. I am interested in just observing the user data after the url loads the result and moves to the next email. This is the code

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         User Search Automation
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://acme.com/usersearch
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  // Email List
  const emailList = [
    'user1@acme.com',
    'user2@acme.com',
    // Add more email addresses here
  ];

  let currentIndex = GM_getValue('currentIndex', 0);

  function reloadPageWithSingleEmail(email) {
    window.location.href = `https://acme.com/usersearch?uid=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`;
  }

  function onPageLoaded() {
    if (currentIndex < emailList.length) {
      const nextEmail = emailList[currentIndex];
      reloadPageWithSingleEmail(nextEmail);

      GM_setValue('currentIndex', currentIndex + 1);
    } else {
      console.log('Search for all emails completed.');
      GM_setValue('currentIndex', 0);
    }
  }

  window.onload = onPageLoaded;
})();
```

Thanks in advance!

I am expecting the page to be reloaded automatically instead of me pressing the reload button each time.